# Google Maps NaN Error After Data Fetch Via API

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

Google Maps plots 5 dots correctly but prints out ERROR when I select > 5 dots to be shown.

The Error is as follows:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'NaN' of undefined
    at visualization_impl.js:2
    at _.Oe.forEach (js?key=MY_API_KEY&callback=initMap&libraries=visualization:191)
    at aha (visualization_impl.js:2)
    at R$ (visualization_impl.js:9)
    at U$.<anonymous> (visualization_impl.js:8)
    at xe.j (js?key=MY_API_KEY&callback=initMap&libraries=visualization:189)
    at Object._.N.trigger (js?key=MY_API_KEY&callback=initMap&libraries=visualization:186)
    at Be (js?key=MY_API_KEY&callback=initMap&libraries=visualization:77)
    at U$._.O.bindTo (js?key=MY_API_KEY&callback=initMap&libraries=visualization:190)
    at d (visualization_impl.js:13)
```

Outcome is that the map is shown on the web page but without any dots. Dots refer to the use of heatmap to play LAT / LON coordinates that are fetched through API GET request.

The code is as follows:

```
function initMap() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/qgea-i56i.json",
        type: "GET",
        data: {
            "$limit": 20,
            "$$app_token": "MYTOKENWASHERE"
        }
    }).done(function (data) {
        debugger
        const heatmapData = [];
        data.forEach((datum) => {
            debugger
            // if(datum.law_cat_cd === filter) { 
            heatmapData.push(new google.maps.LatLng(datum.latitude, datum.longitude));
            // }
        })

        const mapProp = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.7481, -73.9848),
            zoom: 11,
            panControl: false,
            streetViewControl: false,

        };
        const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
        const heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
            data: heatmapData,
            map: map
        });
        heatmap.setMap(map);
    })
}
```

I am processing the result of request inside .done, essentially, .then, so I am truly feeling lost and without any intuition as to why this could be happening. I looked up visualization file on Google Maps docs but that was a waste of time from my perspective.

My guess would be this code is having issue with async but I thought putting Map code inside .done would allow fetching to take place before running the rest of the code... .

Any hints, clues, or comments are appreciated.

Comment: What does the data returned by the API look like?  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.  Your code seems to work fine if I add obviously correct data ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/xmb1qegu/), although it only shows the last data set unless I change the code, see the fiddle)

Comment: @geocodezip, thanks for your reply. The data returned by API call is Array of Objects. Each object has lat / lon key that I then push inside heatmapData array later to display on the map. Example of data returned: 
//
Array of objects: [{},{},{}] where each key:
inx: {latitude: "40.6694", longitude: "-73.91"}
//

I just want to state this once more: On my end, when I specify  "$limit": 5 (in Ajax request), all heatmap dots are shown. But when I specify  "$limit": 20, I get the error specified above in the question.

Comment: That implies there is something wrong with the data from the API somewhere between element 5 and element 20.  We can't tell what that is without seeing the data (at least enough of it to demonstrate your issue).

Comment: @geocodezip, You are absolutely correct!!! Some of the objects did not have LAT / LON coords specified. I used IF statement to take care of it. For some reason, I subconsciously decided that NYPD has immaculate recording system. This is a good lesson. Thank you so much for replying! I really appreciate your help.